# TypeScript simple question..Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts

Tags: typescript

I have the question about TypeScript.
The function should return a value which type is number.
But the code still doesn't work... could anyone give me a hint?
Thanks!

```
export const findOdd = (xs: number[]): number => {
  let count = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < xs.length; j++) {
      if (xs[i] === xs[j]) {
        count++
      }
    }
    if (count % 2 === 1) return xs[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an "else" situation that's not covered with "return"

Comment: Just think about the code, when you get an empty array, you will see that you never reach your return statement.